# How do I set up ibus to use CJK input for the guest session

Tags: ibus, guest-session, chinese

I have searched, and there appear to be several questions from before ibus became the default input method, but they are no longer applicable.

I want to set up the guest session to use zhuyin and pinyin input in traditional characters. This is set up in the main user account, so I copied over the ~/.config/ibus and ~/.xinput* folders to /etc/guest-session/skel, but this doesn't have any effect.

1. Are these the right files to copy?
2. Is this the right place to copy them in 14.04 (with Unity)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm pretty sure those are not the files to copy, I'm not able to tell which files you should copy instead.

But I still have a solution. Create a special purpose user as described in [this tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession) and configure that user using *System Settings -> Text Entry*. Then replace the `/etc/guest-session/skel` folder with a symlink to the home directory of the special purpose user.